# Calling a method from a AsyncFileUpload's UploadedComplete isn't working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asyncfileupload

I have an AsyncFileUpload control that should show a panel and set some text when the upload completes successfully. When I debug it, the event fires and I see that the method is called correctly, but the form doesn't update.

Here's the markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="well well-large">
            <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
                <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" class="search-query" ID="AsyncFileUpload" Width="400px"
                    UploadingBackColor="AppWorkspace" ThrobberID="myThrobber" CompleteBackColor="#068712" OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload_UploadedComplete" />
                <br />
            </form>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="AsyncFileUpload" EventName="UploadedComplete" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panAlertUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panAlert" Visible="false">
            <div class="alert alert-success" id="divAlert" runat="server">
                <button id="Button1" runat="server" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                You shouldn't see this message!
            </div>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panMarquee" Visible="true">
                <div id="Div1" runat="server" class="progress progress-success progress-striped">
                    <div id="ProgressBar" runat="server" class="bar" style="width: 100%"></div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here's the server code:

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AsyncFileUpload.HasFile)
        {

            this.SetMessage(Message.Success);
        }
        else
        {

            this.SetMessage(Message.Fail);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Miscellaneous

    private enum Message { Success, Fail }
    private void SetMessage(Message msg)
    {
        if (msg == Message.Success)
        {
            this.divAlert.InnerText = "Well done! The document appears to have uploaded successfully. Please wait...";
            this.divAlert.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-success");
        }
        else
        {
            this.divAlert.InnerText = "Oh snap! Something broke. Please contact IT right away.";
            this.divAlert.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-error");
        }

        this.panAlert.Visible = true;
        this.panAlertUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
```

It was working just fine when I was using a button as the trigger, but not when I changed it to just the AsyncFileUpload control.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you remove the "EventName" attribute from the trigger?

Comment: @jadarnel27 Just tried it. Nothing happens.

Comment: Is this message only reason to refresh updatepanel or you have some controls which also must be updated after file upload?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy There are controls in the panel that are shown and a messaged is changed. For now, that's all it does. But I'll also need it to start an asynchronous operation.